# Mac mini 2011 upgrade SSD question

Tags: mac, ssd, upgrade, mac-mini, hdd

When I watched a  tutorial on YouTube, it showed that I need to unplug fan, and the IR connector. But, I also read some comments that it's not necessary to remove and could be hanging there when I replace my HDD.

Can anyone could confirm that? The less I remove, the less chance of making mistake; I've heard that tons of people mess up the IR connector.

Comment: What's not necessary to remove? The fan connector, the IR connector or both? IMHO, if you remove it, it goes back where it belongs. Relying on comments in Youtube videos isn't exactly the best idea: anybody can type anything!

Answer (score 1):

> The less I remove, the less chance of making mistake; I've heard that tons of people mess up the IR connector.

While this sentiment is technically true, it's also important to note that if you don't remove what's necessary and you leave things "hanging" you could also damage components because they weren't designed to "just hang;" they are designed to make a connection.

People "mess up" the IR connector because they don't remove it properly. [Ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Mid+2011+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/6634) warns specifically of this:[image]

The bottom line is if you proceed carefully and methodically, you significantly lessen the chance of damaging things.  Most importantly, **don't take shortcuts.**

Comment: Sorry, you haven't answer my question, is that two connectors removal is essential?

Comment: Essential?  No.  Would I try to shortcut my way through it?  Absolutely not.  However, YMMV.  Besides, nowhere in your question did you ask if it was "essential."  You asked if "it's not necessary..."  That's  completely different and what I addressed.